# Youtube Video Resolution Problem

Tags: youtube, mp4

I also posted this question in stack exchange for web applications (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52579/youtube-video-resolution-problem)

I recently uploaded three ~30 second .mp4 files to youtube. The first five seconds of them are displayed in 244p and then at five seconds, youtube switches them to 360p. I would like youtube to display them at 360p from zero seconds. This problem is happening in chrome browser with the html5 player.

**It's important because I need to use these videos as advertisements for my company.**

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the videos:

[image: 2 seconds in, low resolution]

[image: 6 seconds in, high resolution]

For some reason, when embedded the videos do not have this problem, but when watched on youtube and as you can see from the above photos, there is a resolution issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how youtube client works.

Comment: This is normal dynamic selection for Youtube.  In order to start video playing quickly, it starts at a lower quality and then moves to higher quality when sufficient data is buffered.  It is a setting that would have to be chosen by the person watching the video to say they want a fixed resolution rather than dynamic resolution.

Comment: Why does it not do this for internet explorer when I watch the same video? Why does it not do it when I embed the videos like in the above?

Comment: Youtube doesn't always use the same player.  The embedded player and the player in IE either don't support or aren't set by default to use the dynamic adjustment.  It is both client and server dependent.

Comment: Thanks very much AJ. It does seem to depend on the player and there doesn't seem to be a way to dictate which player youtube uses.

Answer (score 1):

For best results on any Youtube upload it is always best to follow the recommended video encoding settings.
Listed here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en

If you have followed those settings exactly and you are still having a problem it is a localized problem that will not affect everyone.

Youtube videos do not play the exact same way on every computer nor every playback.

I watched the videos and as predicted I had no problem with resolution, it was a constant 480p throughout.